# Newly created dependency property is not recognized from another solution

Tags: wpf-controls

I have a question regarding Dependency Properties in WPF.
I am working on a project which uses controls from another package. I modified one of the controls by adding new dependency properties to it. However, when I try to access them in xaml that is in my project, I get error stating that there's no such property in my control. At the same time when I set the values of those properties in style for this control in a file that is located in the same package as the control, everything works. Also, the old dependency properties work fine.

I'm not sure what code to include to illustrate this, please give a hint.

Could anybody at least hint what is going on?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't include in Build-Events of my first solution where the controls reside the path where to copy the respective dll so that the second solution could detect the changes.